# Longwave Radio Receiver, Non-SDR Version

Tags: radio, regenerative

It is my understanding that radio receiver designs change drastically once you get into the sub-MHz range (superhet doesn't seem to make a whole lot of sense at this point). I seem to be leaning into the regenerative-type receiver realm, but am lacking in a fundamental “design principles” guide for such an animal at very low frequencies. My intention is to design a receiver (in hardware, not software) that can lock onto the WWVB timecode signal (60 kHz carrier, BPSK encoded) in areas relatively far from the transmitter and/or in high multipath environments (urban areas, mountainous terrain, etc.).

I believe the simplest implementation here would be to use a tuned LC receiver that is then run through a simple gain stage, but the vast majority of what I’ve been able to find either utilize the no-longer-produced TBA120, or don’t provide equations for component choice (i.e., you can find a circuit for a specific frequency, but no equations to back up the selections to assist in converting it to a different frequency).

A lot of really good examples give design equations for regenerative receivers, but none I’ve found claim to go below 200 kHz, let alone all the way down to 60 kHz. For example: the "RX1LM/HF" receiver noted [here](https://www.qsl.net/on6mu/schemas/generalcoveragereceiver.htm) only lists coverage down to 140kHz. What would I have to change to get it to perform well at 60kHz?

---

EDIT: Sorry, as many have pointed out, I neglected to ask a question.  "Is there a good reference for building receivers in this frequency range (including equations for component selection)?"

Comment: Yep, you really build up suspense for the actual question, and then forgot to ask it!

Comment: (by the way, does it *really* make sense to preclude a software-defined system for something that gives you timecode data which is basically only useful for software? It's no surprise designs in this range tend to directly sample the RF or even an *upconverted* "IF", seeing that even cheapest microcontrollers are plenty fast enough for that)

Comment: by the way, I don't really think multipath is 1. a problem you would *want* to solve in analog domain (the only commercial receiver class I can think of that did that were late top-notch analog TVs, which never were a commercial success, as doing it in analog domain was nearly prohibitively expensive, a cheap digital system can do much better and also, digital TV was introduced to deal with exactly that problem, among others) and,

Comment: 2. I don't think multipath is a problem you *need* to solve, as the WWVB bandwidth is so ridiculously small that you simply can't see any significant multipath (but "significant" is up to you to define, so I might be wrong about what you want to do); however, if you do need to combat multipath, you *will* need to build an SDR-based receiver – you just don't want *that* magnitude of analog delay lines to be able to do that.

Comment: Because 60 kHz is a frequency that even modest op-amps can work with, there is no need to bring down conversion, IFs, tuned LC filters, etc.

Comment: You could use ac mixer to upconvert to 455KHz so it would be superhet with conventional IF circuits.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: > the vast majority of what I’ve been able to find
Can you link some of these inappropriate schematics? We may be able to offer guidance on component replacement or the equations governing their selection.

Comment: If you want to do old school analog, 60 kHz is a fine IF frequency for narrowband signals. So, design a superhet with that IF, but without the converter stage.